# ipv6 addresses acting oddly on my ubuntu system

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ipv6

trying to get the basics of IPv6 working on my system. If I do:

```
sudo ip -6 address show enp2s0
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2601:646:9780:4729:241b:3a90:ee0f:25f0/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 319298sec preferred_lft 9212sec
    inet6 2601:646:9780:4729:966:9e4c:672d:15ca/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic 
       valid_lft 319298sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 2601:646:9780:4729:550e:60d0:d47:d8a4/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic 
       valid_lft 319298sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 2601:646:9780:4729:e9c:5834:f3dd:e05b/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 319298sec preferred_lft 319298sec
    inet6 fe80::ce93:ee7e:7c15:2a67/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Looks like I have ipv6 addressing, right?

I can also ping myself:

```
ping 2601:646:9780:4729:241b:3a90:ee0f:25f0
PING 2601:646:9780:4729:241b:3a90:ee0f:25f0(2601:646:9780:4729:241b:3a90:ee0f:25f0) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2601:646:9780:4729:241b:3a90:ee0f:25f0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from 2601:646:9780:4729:241b:3a90:ee0f:25f0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
```

Buuuuttttt, if I try to ping something in the outside world using IPv6, it does not work:

```
addr www.example.com
Addresses for host: www.example.com
Address: type: AF_INET Socket type: SOCK_STREAM Address: 93.184.216.34
Address: type: AF_INET Socket type: SOCK_DGRAM Address: 93.184.216.34
Address: type: AF_INET Socket type: SOCK_RAW Address: 93.184.216.34
Address: type: AF_INET6 Socket type: SOCK_STREAM Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
Address: type: AF_INET6 Socket type: SOCK_DGRAM Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
Address: type: AF_INET6 Socket type: SOCK_RAW Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946

ping 93.184.216.34
PING 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=10.2 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=10.2 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=9.92 ms

ping 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
connect: Network is unreachable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have IPv6 addressing, but not necessarily an IPv6 *default route*. Check `ip -6 r`.

The default route (as well as SLAAC-based LAN addressing) is distributed using broadcast ICMPv6 Router Advertisement packets. It could be that your router previously had but lost its IPv6 access, or for whatever other reason isn't advertising itself as the default gateway, even though it still has a public address prefix.

Run `sudo rdisc6 enp2s0` to see the contents of the RA that your router broadcasts – make sure it has "Router lifetime" set to a non-zero number (usually 1⁄2h or more). The tool is often in the 'ndisc6' package.

---

Side note: Addresses with the "temporary" flag will change every 10 hours – they are RFC 4941 "Privacy Extensions" addresses used for all outgoing connections. (In the list, you already have two "expired" addresses.) If you need an address that is useful for *incoming* connections, use the `..e05b` one without 'temporary' next to it – it will always remain static for this computer. (The 'mngtmpaddr' next to it is not a problem.)